# Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit

Tags: java

I got following exception during deploy:

> 15:52:40,127 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."WebApp.war#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."WebApp.war#primary": Failed to start service
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_51]

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Error while parsing file: Member.hbm.xml
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1255)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1047)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:692)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:106)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:474)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:470)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:643)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:681)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:1247)
 ... 10 more

Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory  Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:76)
... 15 more
```

im trying hours to handle this.Does anybodey know what to do? The idea of deleting all hibernate dependency wasnt a good idea..any other idea?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Error while parsing file: Member.hbm.xml - post your entity mapping and persistence settings

Comment: got it...had to remove all hibernate dependencies out of my pom.xml and out of the lib folder

Comment: wasnt a good idea..any other idea??